# Dataframes: Finding lowest price based on criteria

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a csv file with a list of laptops and specs. I want to find the lowest price based on laptops with screens greater than 15 inches. What is wrong with my code?

```
laptops_15 = laptops_cleaned.loc[(laptops_cleaned['screen_size_inches'] > 15), laptops_cleaned['price_euros'].min()]

print(laptops_15)

#TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [bool] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

I don't understand why Python doesn't take the min price of all the True values?

Answer (score 1):

can you provide an example of datas?

I tried to reproduce your situation and the error message I get is the following

```
TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [800] of <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

This is expected because you are using a value of price as an index, where loc is expecting whatever you are using as an index in your dataframe (ints if unspecified). I believe what you are trying to achieve in this:

```
laptops_cleaned[laptops_cleaned['screen_size_inches'] > 15]['price_euros'].idxmin()
```

which gives you the index of your table entry such that the column 'price_euros' is minimum, amongst the entries such that the column 'screen_size_inches' is larger than 15.

To get the minimum value rather than the minimum index, use the `min()` method rather that `idxmin()`

```
laptops_cleaned[laptops_cleaned['screen_size_inches'] > 15]['price_euros'].min()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
laptops_15 = laptops_cleaned['price_euros'][laptops_cleaned['screen_size_inches'] > 15].min()
```